Pasting only values
I created a macro to paste only the text (like Ctrl+Shift+V in Sheets) into the next empty cell after the last used one, but it's not working properly.
Here's the code, i'm using a variable instead of Range.PasteSpecial
Sub pasteSub()

    Dim baseSheet As Worksheet, nextCell As Range, lastRow As Long
    
    Set baseSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE")
    
    lastRow = baseSheet.Cells(baseSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Set nextCell = baseSheet.Cells(lastRow, "D")
    
    nextCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub

When it reaches the nextCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues line, it returns the following error
PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

What does "not working properly" mean?

I edited it, forgot to put the error, sorry.

Are you copying something manually, prior to running this code?

Yes, it's a table from another website, the table have 4 columns (D to G). When i paste using the "match destination formatting" manually it works.

I would switch on 'Record Macro', go through the steps manually, and then review the code that was generated.

I can't see where you've copied anything to be able to paste it.

I copy it manually, and then the macro paste the code. I'll record a macro and see the steps so i can try to fix my code.

Try also another code. Your variant will work if you copy from Excel.
On Error Resume Next
nextCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
baseSheet.PasteSpecial
On Error GoTo 0
Application.CutCopyMode = False


That'll just hide the error.  The error will still happen and nothing will get pasted.  The user just won't see the message.

This needs to be thoroughly tested and adjusted depending on what and from what source you are copying.

Yeah, that didn't work. It just hid the error, it's almost the same code, but the On Error Resume Next is just making the code repeat itself. I'll post the result when i find it.

That worked pretty good.
It goes to the next empty cell after the last filled cell using Offset + 1 and then it pastes using the "manual mode" from the Macro Record.
Sub botPrincipal()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Sheets("BASE").Select
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Cells(lastRow, "D").Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    
    Sheets("NOVOS").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

